# Dependency injection with custom Doctrine 2 hydrator

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm setting up a custom hydrator in Doctrine 2 in a Symfony 2 project, but for it to do what it needs it requires another service. The [documentation for custom hydrators](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) only shows how to provide a hydrator class, so there's no way to inject dependencies.

For example:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('CustomHydrator', 'MyProject\Hydrators\CustomHydrator');
```

I suspect Doctrine is initialising the hydrators itself and as such any dependencies would need to be passed through some other Doctrine classes first.

Is there a way to provide a custom "hydration factory" or similar to Doctrine that would allow injection of additional dependencies? Custom hydrators seem fairly limited without this capability.

---

**Answer:** Thanks to Denis V

I got this working as follows. I can't post the actual code so I've put together some dummy placeholders so you can see how it fits together.

*src/Acme/ExampleBundle/resources/config/services.yml*

```
services:
    doctrine.orm.entity_manager.abstract:
        class:          Acme\ExampleBundle\Entity\DoctrineEntityManager
        factory_class:  Acme\ExampleBundle\Entity\DoctrineEntityManager
        factory_method: create
        abstract:       true
        calls:
            - [ setMyDependency, [@acme.my_custom_service]]
```

*src/Acme/ExampleBundle/Entity/DoctrineEntityManager.php*

```
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Entity;

use Acme\ExampleBundle\Hydrator\MyHydrator;
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager as BaseEntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\ORMException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

class DoctrineEntityManager extends BaseEntityManager
{
    protected $myDependency;

    /**
     * Note: This must be redefined as Doctrine's own entity manager has its own class name hardcoded in.
     */
    public static function create($conn, Configuration $config, EventManager $eventManager = null)
    {
        if (!$config->getMetadataDriverImpl()) {
            throw ORMException::missingMappingDriverImpl();
        }

        switch (true) {
            case (is_array($conn)):
                $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(
                    $conn, $config, ($eventManager ?: new EventManager())
                );
                break;

            case ($conn instanceof Connection):
                if ($eventManager !== null && $conn->getEventManager() !== $eventManager) {
                     throw ORMException::mismatchedEventManager();
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid argument: " . $conn);
        }

        return new self($conn, $config, $conn->getEventManager());
    }

    public function setMyDependency($myCustomService)
    {
        $this->myDependency = $myCustomService;
    }

    public function newHydrator($hydrationMode)
    {
        if ($hydrationMode == 'MyHydrationMode') {
            return new MyHydrator($this, $this->myDependency);
        }

        return parent::newHydrator($hydrationMode);
    }
}
```

*src/Acme/ExampleBundle/Hydrator/MyHydrator.php*

```
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Hydrator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator;

class MyHydrator extends ObjectHydrator
{
    protected $myDependency;

    public __construct(EntityManager $em, $myDependency)
    {
        parent::__construct($em);

        $this->myDependency = $myDependency;
    }

    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        /* hydration stuff with my dependency here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this in your config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        hydrators:
            CustomHydrator: MyProject\Hydrators\CustomHydrator
```

**UPDATE**

As you cannot inject anything to the Hydrator itself, you can instead create a custom EntityManager (that you suggested yourself).

It can be done this way:

```
services:  
    name_of_your_custom_manager:
        class: %doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class%
        factory_service:  doctrine
        factory_method:   getManager
        arguments: ["name_of_your_custom_manager"]
        calls:
            - [ setCustomDependency, ["@acme_bundle.custom_dependency"] ]
```

Comment: That still leaves it up to Doctrine to instantiate the hydrator, which means I can't pass in additional dependencies.

Comment: Just to clarify, am I right that you want to inject dependecy to the Hydrator itself, not to the entity manager?

Comment: That's correct. I think the only way to do this may be by injecting it into a custom entity manager, which can then inject it to the hydrator.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was going to add to my question. EntityManager is available in the Hydrator, and thus you can access any injected dependency.

Comment: Aha, that looks like it could work, thank you! I didn't realise there was a factory service for entity managers. I'll give it a try and update here.

Answer (score -1):

Really good answer but please be advised that Doctrine maintainers explicitly said [not to extend Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L52) and I suppose that in the future they will make it final to enforce this.

So instead of the proposed solution without breaking rules here is the cleaner solution:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Doctrine\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\Decorator\EntityManagerDecorator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\ORMException;

class EntityManager extends EntityManagerDecorator
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $wrapped)
    {
        parent::__construct($wrapped);
    }

    public static function create($conn, Configuration $config, EventManager $eventManager = null)
    {
        if ( ! $config->getMetadataDriverImpl()) {
            throw ORMException::missingMappingDriverImpl();
        }

        switch (true) {
            case (is_array($conn)):
                $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(
                    $conn, $config, ($eventManager ?: new EventManager())
                );
                break;

            case ($conn instanceof Connection):
                if ($eventManager !== null && $conn->getEventManager() !== $eventManager) {
                    throw ORMException::mismatchedEventManager();
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid argument: " . $conn);
        }

        return new EntityManager($conn, $config, $conn->getEventManager());
    }
}
```

And now define this service in your services.xml file as decorating the desired entity manager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">


    <services>
        <defaults autowire="true" autoconfigure="true" public="false" />

        <service
            id="decorated.doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
            class="App\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"
            decorates="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
        >
            <argument type="service" id="decorated.doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager.inner" />
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

Comment: I dont see that you made any inject to this decorator that was requested.

Comment: What I wanted to point out is to not extend the base entity manager.